# std::same_as концепт не вызывается

Tags: c++, c++20, concept

```
#include <concepts>

int f(std::integral auto);
int f(std::same_as<char> auto);
const auto x = f('?');
```

Почему программа не компилируется?

> error C2668: 'f': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: Очевидно, что оба концепта подходят. Вот компилятор и не знает

Comment: @KoVadim но второй же тот же тип значит его надо выбрать

Comment: "тот тип" был бы, если бы было написано `int f(char )`. А так, просто два шаблона, со своими ограничениями на тип аргумента.

Comment: @Chorkov почему 2 ограничение не срабатывает, если оно лучше?

Comment: @energo он не лучше. И то и другое - концепты. Все подходящие концепты равноправны.